# Disabling Android Camera automatic thumbnail

Tags: android, camera, thumbnails, automatic-storage

I've seen that Android automatically generates a thumbnail when taking a photo, and saves it as an extra with the key "data". Is it possible to disable that action, as to save space in the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've seen that Android automatically generates a thumbnail when taking a photo, and saves it as an extra with the key "data".

No, it does not. *Camera apps* may generate thumbnails and put them in a `data` extra in the `Intent` used with `setResult()`. Android, the operating system, does not.

> Is it possible to disable that action, as to save space in the device?

I do not know what "space" you think you will "save". That thumbnail is held briefly in system RAM. It is not stored on disk.

If you are a programmer, and if you are writing an Android app, and if you are using an `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent` with `startActivityForResult()` to invoke a third-party camera app, then you can include `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to indicate where you want a full-sized image to be written. According to [the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE), the `data` extra is not needed in that case. Some camera apps will then skip that extra.

However, developers of third-party camera apps are welcome to do whatever they want. If they want to create the `data` extra on every `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` request, that is their decision to make, as they are the ones writing the camera apps.